# I can't figure out why UnsatisfiedLinkError appears

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface, minecraft

I am unable to find why my codes returns an UnsatisfiedLinkError.

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: 'void fr.bastoup.spigotplusplus.link.CPPLink.loadPlugin(java.lang.String)'
at fr.bastoup.spigotplusplus.link.CPPLink.loadPlugin(Native Method) ~[?:?]
at fr.bastoup.spigotplusplus.link.CPPLink.loadPlugin(CPPLink.java:17) ~[?:?]
at fr.bastoup.spigotplusplus.SpigotPlusPlus.onEnable(SpigotPlusPlus.java:11) ~[?:?]
at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin.setEnabled(JavaPlugin.java:263) ~[spigot-1.16.4.jar:git-Spigot-a19903d-5b74714]
at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPluginLoader.enablePlugin(JavaPluginLoader.java:351) ~[spigot-1.16.4.jar:git-Spigot-a19903d-5b74714]
at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.enablePlugin(SimplePluginManager.java:480) ~[spigot-1.16.4.jar:git-Spigot-a19903d-5b74714]
at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_16_R3.CraftServer.enablePlugin(CraftServer.java:494) ~[spigot-1.16.4.jar:git-Spigot-a19903d-5b74714]
at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_16_R3.CraftServer.enablePlugins(CraftServer.java:408) ~[spigot-1.16.4.jar:git-Spigot-a19903d-5b74714]
at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R3.MinecraftServer.loadWorld(MinecraftServer.java:435) ~[spigot-1.16.4.jar:git-Spigot-a19903d-5b74714]
at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R3.DedicatedServer.init(DedicatedServer.java:218) ~[spigot-1.16.4.jar:git-Spigot-a19903d-5b74714]
at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R3.MinecraftServer.w(MinecraftServer.java:809) ~[spigot-1.16.4.jar:git-Spigot-a19903d-5b74714]
at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R3.MinecraftServer.lambda$0(MinecraftServer.java:164) ~[spigot-1.16.4.jar:git-Spigot-a19903d-5b74714]
```

However my .so file is correctly generated and seems to be loaded as there is no error when I try to load it.

```
$ nm -DC native/Linux/x86_64/cpplink.so 
                 U __cxa_atexit
                 w __cxa_finalize
                 w __gmon_start__
                 w _ITM_deregisterTMCloneTable
                 w _ITM_registerTMCloneTable
00000000000011a9 T Java_fr_bastoup_spigotplusplus_link_CPPLink_loadPlugin(JNIEnv_*, _jclass**, _jstring**)
                 U std::ios_base::Init::Init()
                 U std::ios_base::Init::~Init()
                 U std::cout
                 U std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::endl<char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&)
                 U std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::operator<< <std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*)
```

I searched for an answer for more than 1 month and I have no idea. If someone knows, that'd be great !

Here is the github repo: https://github.com/BastouP411/SpigotPlusPlus

Thanks !

Comment: Could it be that the binding mechanism is confused because there's also a non-native method with the name `loadPlugin`?

Comment: @Oo.oO I am using System.load and not System.loadLibrary and providing an absolute path to the .so, It seems to be the right way to do it looking at the documentation.

Comment: @user2543253 no that's not it. the native method is marked with the "native" keyword, so it cannot be confused in any way.

Answer (score 0):

OK I had just forgotten to include my header file in my .cpp.
It's solved now !